# How to resolve an undefined value when retrieving data from one controller to another controller's view in cakephp using elements

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to retrieve data from another controller to display it in the PagesController's view using an element. I have a table

```
service_categories(id, service_category);
```

my ServiceCategoriesController looks like this

```
public function category() {
    $serviceCategories = $this->paginate();
    if ($this->request->is('requested')) {
        return $servicesCategories;
    } else {
        $this->set('serviceCategories', $servicesCategories);
    }
}
```

my category.ctp element looks like this

```
 <?php
$serviceCategories = $this->set('serviceCategories/category');

foreach ($serviceCategories as $serviceCategory):
    echo $serviceCategory['ServiceCategory']['service_category'];
endforeach;
```

But I seem to get an undefined value of "$serviceCategories" when I create an alert before the foreach loop. Please assist! What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the answer after turning on brain:

In your element replace:

```
$serviceCategories = $this->set('serviceCategories/category');
```

with

```
$serviceCategories = $this->requestAction('service_categories/category');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but values are still undefined